# Implementation knpPaginator in symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

| Q | A |
| --- | --- |
| Bundle version | x.y.z |
| Symfony version | 6.0.4 |
| PHP version | 8.1.6 |

#### Support Question

Hi,

I am asking for help in creating the pagination for the index.  I've tried many ways and everyone has failed.
Below I enclose the data for the project:

[View MySql and componnets symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO8aE.jpg)

[Controller to implement paginator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwLNk.jpg)

What I must change for it to work?

[Code KnpPaginator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXBuI.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg8Yq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this pagination implementation in my old project, look maybe u can find something for you.

```
/**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param PaginatorService $paginatorService
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/service', name: 'service_index')]
    public function index(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        PaginatorService $paginatorService,
        Request $request
    ): Response {
        return $this->render('service/index.html.twig', [
            'services' =>
                $paginatorService->paginate($entityManager->getRepository(Service::class)->findAll(), $request)
        ]);
    }


class PaginatorService
{
    public function __construct(
        private PaginatorInterface $paginator,
    ) {
    }

    public function paginate($query, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1),
            15
        );
    }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="pagination mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
            {{ knp_pagination_render(services, '/pagination/bootstrap_v5_pagination.html.twig') }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also look at your movie entity namespace declaration